# start another Jenkinsjob from within my declarative Jenkinsfile but just one time

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

i want to start another Jenkinsjob from within my declarative Jenkinsfile. I do that with following command:

build job: 'My-gitea-org/my-gitea-repo2/master', wait: true

This sub-job (my-gitea-repo2) will be triggered by several other jobs. So i want to check if the sub-job is currently running and i want to wait in my main job until its finished and then start the sub-job. Is that possible?

Regards

Dave

Comment: Just disable concurrent builds in the configuration of the sub job.

Comment: Do you depend on the response of the "sub-job" to complete the "main job"?

Comment: We have one "COMMON" component which possibly will also be modified, when a "SUBCOMPONENT" is modified. Not in every case but sometime. When we push the "COMMON" component, the build for that will start and take ~10 minutes. Now we push the change into the "SUBCOMPONENT" and the build will also start. What we want to reach is, that "SUBCOMPONENT" will check if "COMMON" is running. When "YES" it should wait until "COMMON" is finished and go on. When "NO" we want to go on with "SUBCOMPONENT" without any other action.